# Returning positon.left with Bootstrap offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems pretty simple but is stumping me.

I am trying to get the left position of a div positioned with Bootstrap 3's column offset.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4" id="formholder">
```

I get 15px with `positon.left` ... the Bootstrap gutter.

```
console.log($('#formholder').position().left);
```

Anyone know how to get the left position from the edge of the page with column offset?

Comment: have you tried `.offset().left` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset()` instead of `position()`

Try this and check it in your console

```
console.log($('#formholder').offset().left);
```